# Stuffing React component in Backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, reactjs

I am getting a React error:

> Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container
>   is not a DOM element.

I think I know what the problem is but I don't know how to solve it. The problem is that I want to reference a div element id in the render function, but the html in the render function has not been rendered to the DOM yet by the time I want to stick something into that html. So my question is - how can I reference an element id of the html from my render function before it is rendered to the DOM? this has become what I think to be a jQuery question.

Here's the code in the render function of a simple Backbone.View:

```
     var self = this;

     var ret = EJS.render(template, {});

     this.$el.html(ret); //nice, but hasn't been rendered to the DOM yet

     React.render(
        <TimerExample start={Date.now()} />,
         self.el    //this works no problemo
    );

     React.render(
       <MenuExample items={ ['Home', 'Services', 'About', 'Contact us'] } />,
       $('#react-menu-example-div-id')[0]  //this is *not* working, what is the right call here, so that this view can coexist with the above React view?
     );
```

the first `React.render` call works if it is by itself. But the second React.render doesn't work and is the one throwing the error.

My template just looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="react-menu-example-div-id">menu example goes here</div>
</div>
```

my Backbone.View in question is creating its own el. What I am trying to do might be completely whack - I just want to render two separate/unrelated/different React components in the same Backbone view. Is there a good pattern for this?

Comment: Can't you do `$(self.el).find('#react-menu-example-div-id')[0]`?

Comment: perhaps. will try it tomorrow. the jquery find function can search HTML that is not in the DOM?

Comment: Yes: https://jsfiddle.net/09jeomqs/

Comment: While that's true about jQuery, it would still not work, as noveyak explains in an answer below.

Comment: @HannesJohansson yeah that worked, thanks. the find( ) function for jQuery seems to be able to find HTML elements that aren't in the DOM yet, very handy indeed methinks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first render statement into self.el is replacing the contents of the DOM for that element. So by the time your second render call is made the #react-menu-example div no longer exists. You can fix this by just rendering to another element inside the parent. Although in general I think it would be best to have as much of your templating/rendering in React and not use the backbone view for too much of the templating.

Here is an example of rendering to two different ids inside the same backbone view

https://jsfiddle.net/sa4vvtjL/2/

Template

```
<div id="search_container">a</div>

<script type="text/template" id="search_template">
    <div>
        <div id="placeholder1"></div>
        <div id="react-menu-example-div-id"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

JS

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (<div> {this.props.start} </div>)
    }
});

var Hello2 = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (<div> lala </div>)
    }
});

var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var template = _.template($("#search_template").html(), {});
        this.$el.html(template);

        React.render(
            <Hello start={Date.now()} />,
            $('#placeholder1')[0] 
        );

        React.render(
            <Hello2  />,
            $('#react-menu-example-div-id')[0] 
        );

    }
});

var search_view = new SearchView({
    el: $("#search_container")
});
```

Comment: I actually think you need to use jQuery's find() function instead, like so: $(this.el).find('#placeholder1')[0], I don't think the above will work as is because the template won't be in the DOM yet, and $('#age') will only look in real DOM , can you confirm?

Comment: see this question and answer for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547521/backbone-js-parent-vs-child-views

Comment: this.$el.html(template) I believe places it in the dom. Check my JSfiddle and you can see the 2 react views rendering in the different attach points.

Comment: ahh yes, it will place it in the DOM because you passed the el in new SearchView({el:...})...however if you are interested in learning something new click the link above as how jQuery.find() can help you out if your parent view creates its own el that doesn't prexist

Answer (score 2):

What is actually says it's that element with id 'react-menu-example-div-id' is not on the page yet.

I can observe you are using jquery, so why not:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
React.render(
       <MenuExample items={ ['Home', 'Services', 'About', 'Contact us'] } />,
       $('#react-menu-example-div-id')[0]
     );
});
```